# On Spinner OnSelectedItem Listner Error

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have one Spinner Named drpcat. I am getting error
**11-27 19:42:00.923: E/ViewRootImpl(21825): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null**

here is my code

```
 drpcat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

             if(isdefaultcatselection) 
             {                     
                    isdefaultcatselection = false;
             } 
             else 
             {
                 category=drpcat.getSelectedItem().toString();

                loadmake();     

             }


        }



        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

Comment: Can You paste whole stacktrace?

Comment: did you get a solution for this? i am having a similar problem, but it just closes my dropdown view